# Draw Triangle by turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am a beginner to python and found a code to draw triangle by Turtle as below code

```
def drawPolygon(t, vertices):
    t.up()
    (x, y) = vertices[-1]
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.down()
    for (x, y) in vertices:
        t.goto(x, y)

import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
drawPolygon(t, [(20, 20), (-20, 20), (-20, -20)])

turtle.done()
```

1st thing I don't understand is this: `(x, y) = vertices[-1]`.

2nd thing I don't understand is this: `for (x, y) in vertices:`.

Comment: Looks like you took step 2, without taking step 1.  I would suggest learn basic python  control structures and data structures to understand the programs.   If you insist on breaking a leg and learning lessons while learning how to ride bike, there are few helpful souls to support also :-)

Comment: Thanks @aartist for your comment, actually I am learning now the basics of Python from book and found it hard to understand the previous lines (same book and working with the book sequence), I didn't expect it use a list to assign variables, but I'll be sure to review the basics again to be sure to understand te code easily in the future :)

Comment: https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, vertices is a list passed into the function, so `(x, y) = vertices[-1]`just access the last element in the list (-1 means first from the end), and (x,y) is a tuple to store the values returned. `for (x, y) in vertices:` is just a way of iterating through all elements in the list vertices.

Refer these for more info:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

Answer (score 1):

The first line: `(x, y) = vertices[-1]` is basically saying

> Take the last element in list `vertices`, which is `(-20, -20)`, and assigned its elements to `x` and `y`.

So `x` would be equal to -20, and `y` would be equal to -20 as well.

The second line: `for (x, y) in vertices:`. That line creates a [`for loop`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

This specific loop goes through the list `vertices`, and takes each value, and makes the turtle go to that value with the `.goto()` function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

> `(x, y) = vertices[-1]`

The subscription of `-1` means to get the last element of the array, and in this case, it's `(-20, -20)`.

---

> `for (x, y) in vertices:`

Will make python iterate through each element in the array, during each iteration, the element of the iteration is accessible by calling `(x, y)`.